# How can I redirectveriable veriable from object to my haracter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have 2 scripts one on player :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPositionCorrection : MonoBehaviour
{

    Transform _playerTransform;
    public float _xAxys;
    public float _newXAxys;

    public GameObject _changerPlayerPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        _playerTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "ChangePlayerPosition")
        {
            float _newXAxys = this.GetComponent<ChangePositionOn>()._newPostion;
            
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (transform.position.z != 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(_xAxys, _playerTransform.position.y, _playerTransform.position.z);
        }
    }
```

and second on object :

```
public class ChangePositionOn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float _newPostion = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I using Unity 2022.1.19f1 and C#.

Thank you for your healp,
Michal

I would like to have several object in my game and when player will collide with them change location on x axis.

Unfortunately every time i have this error message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerPositionCorrection.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerPositionCorrection.cs:23)
```

Comment: Many typos make this hard to read: correct spelling errors.

Comment: The exception indicates that the object you are trying to GetComponent on does not have that component. Check in the editor if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the ChangePositionOn script is attached to the player
   gameObject.
2. remove the float decalaration in the function because it makes it a
   local variable
3. replace your function with this instead

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("ChangePlayerPosition"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Check if Collided With : "+ other.gameObject.name);
                _newXAxys = this.GetComponent<ChangePositionOn>()._newPostion;
                Debug.Log("New XAxys value : "+ _newXAxys );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, Error doesn't appear but after collision with object should change xaxis however nothing has been change.

Comment: Read my edit and send screenshot if failed

Comment: Its works, however not as supposed do. Maybe will be easier if i show what i wanna to achieve. 

https://imgur.com/5zxRI0u

Now we hold data the _newXAxys into player element. However this data supposed be in second element with collider (not related into player Prefab).When the player collide with this element should take this data (in our case float number) and change positions (what already works).

Answer (score 0):

Make a new script PositionCorrector and Attach it to the Collider GameObject :

```
using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  
  public class PositionCorrector : MonoBehaviour
  {
  //this should be attached to Collider GameObject
  
     //this is the X value you want to change to, each collider can have a different number.
      public float _newXAxys=4;

      private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
      {
          if (other.CompareTag("PlayerTag"))
          {
              //changing the x axys of the player position
              other.transform.position = new Vector3(_newXAxys, other.transform.position.y, other.transform.position.z);
              
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Guys it's work :) For someone who also like me would like to use this script please remember to change in PlayerPositionCorrection :

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("ChangePlayerPosition"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Check if Collided With : " + other.gameObject.name);
            _newXAxys = other.GetComponent<PositionCorrector>()._newXAxys;
            Debug.Log("New XAxys value : " + _newXAxys);
        }
    }

Thank you for yor help !! You are amazing :)